# From which version onwards does Apache Tomcat provide IPv6 support?

Tags: tomcat, ipv6

I have been searching truckloads of documentation but the answer to this simple question seems to be so evasive.

Basically, we need to know if Tomcat 7.x supports IPv6 or not. If it does, what is the configuration one needs to do for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat7 absolutely has no problems with IPv6. I am using this setup for some time now. Even Tomcat6 I sucessfully ran on IPv6.

I'd expect that it does not depend on the version of tomcat but the version of your JVM. Java supports IPv6 since version 1.4.